# аргонианин(-)возница

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, раздельно-дефис

> Караван направлялся в Гидеон, и, как сказали Скотти аргониане, он мог отправиться с ними после того, как они закончат разгружать ягоды.
>
> — Давно ли они были собраны? — спросил Скотти, разглядывая омерзительную поклажу.
>
> — Их, конечно же, собирают в месяц Последнего Зерна, — сообщил ему **аргонианин-возница**.

Нужен ли дефис после "аргонианин"? Аргониане — это раса полуящеров-полулюдей.

На данный момент я понимаю правила так:

- Если второе слово несет главную смысловую нагрузку, а первое слово лишь описывает второе, то дефис не ставится. *Она ждала своего солдата мужа.* Главная идея тут — то, что она ждала мужа. То, что ее муж был солдатом, — дескриптивная, вторичная информация.
- Если первое слово главное, а второе слово лишь описывает первое, дефис ставится. *Она ждала своего мужа-солдата.*

Я полагаю, что в примере выше дефис не нужен. К Скотти обратился возница, который к тому же был аргонианином.

С другой стороны, "аргонианин-возница" можно интерпретировать как "один из аргониан, который оказался возницей", но я не уверен, насколько такая интерпретация возможна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваш пример из классической литературы:

***Осетин-извозчик*** неутомимо погонял лошадей, чтоб успеть до ночи взобраться на Койшаурскую гору, и во все горло распевал песни (М.Ю. Лермонтов).

При дефисном написании на первом месте стоит определяемое слово, а приложение — на втором. То есть автор пишет об осетине, который является извозчиком, национальность для него важнее.

Вариант ***извозчик-осетин*** тоже возможен, но тогда это будет извозчик, по национальности осетин.

В вашем примере всё то же самое. **Автор сам  сделал выбор**, написав: **аргонианин-возница.**

Для него более важной информацией является указание на расу: **аргонианин, который был возницей**.